# How to delete all segments from Elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Solr, to delete all documents and the segments we perform `*:*` query in the delete request.

How the same can be achieved in elastic search?
Can I use `_delete_by_query` with `match_all`? Or do I need to delete the index and recreate it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [delete index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html) if you want to delete all documents from your index.

[Delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) will be useful if you want to delete documents matching some criteria(you can specify that in your search query), Having `match_all` query will not be I guess costly as compare to delete index API, and only benefit is that you will not have to create index mapping and setting(skelton of your index) which anyway won't take time to create.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
So, you mean even `match_all` will delete all the segments and not mark all documents as deleted and add new docs in new segments keeping old data too?